# pkg-config can't find opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, pkg-config

I installed opencv on a lubuntu 12.10 distro. Then when I try to compile a code which is using opencv it says it can't find it. So I try in a terminal :

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

It answers me that it can't find opencv. But the files are installed in /usr/lib. I don't understand why it can't find them.

Comment: You need to have the package `libopencv-dev` installed.

Comment: I had only installed libcv, I added libopencv and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems you have found your answer. Could you please answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: Installing that package solved my isssue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to put `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` at the end of your g++ line. For example :

```
g++ test.cpp -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Compiles

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` test.cpp -o test
```

Doesn't compile and have undefined reference.

Answer (score 14):

For OpenCV 4 you might have to use:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4
```

(Note the 4 in the end!)

Answer (score 2):

From OpenCV 4:

add `-DOPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=YES` to cmake build arguments.

Use `YES`, `ON` is not working anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Many good answers (and comments). Adding a comprehensive one that (hopefully) addresses the entire problem.
Also, working on updated environment (at answer time): *Ubuntu 22* (with *OpenCV**4***).

According to [[FreeDesktop]: pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config):

> pkg-config is a helper tool used when compiling applications and libraries. It helps you insert the correct compiler options on the command line so an application can use gcc -o test test.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0` for instance, rather than hard-coding values on where to find glib (or other libraries).

Example:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q015113753]> . ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> pkg-config --version
> 0.29.2
> [064bit prompt]> 
> [064bit prompt]> # Search for (older) OpenCV
> [064bit prompt]> pkg-config --modversion opencv
> Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
> Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
> to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
> No package 'opencv' found
> [064bit prompt]> 
> [064bit prompt]> # Search for OpenCV4
> [064bit prompt]> pkg-config --modversion opencv4
> 4.5.4
> ```

But how does *Pkg-Config* determine that information (and how come *OpenCV4* works while *OpenCV* doesn't)?
The answer is simple: it reads (and displays information from) *.pc* files. More details can be found at:

- [[FreeDesktop.People]: Guide to pkg-config](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Edbn/pkg-config-guide.html)
- `man pgk-config`
- The error message from the (above) failed command might also give some pointers

Worth mentioning that it's similar to *CMake*'s *Find*.cmake* files.

So, *Pkg-Config* searches for (*.pc*) files in a list of default folders. More can be added by specifying them in *PKG_CONFIG_PATH*.

> ```
> [064bit prompt]> # Default search paths (each on separate line) for .pc files
> [064bit prompt]> pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config | tr ":" "\n"
> /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
> /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
> /usr/local/share/pkgconfig
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
> /usr/lib/pkgconfig
> /usr/share/pkgconfig
> ```

Back to *OpenCV(4)*:

> ```
> [064bit prompt]> pkg-config --debug --modversion opencv4 2>&1 | grep "Reading 'opencv4"
> Reading 'opencv4' from file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/opencv4.pc'
> ```

And the actual package owning the file:

> ```
> [064bit prompt]> dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/opencv4.pc
> libopencv-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/opencv4.pc
> ```

So, in order for *OpenCV4* to be *Pkg-Config*-able, installing the *OpenCV* *.deb* (and dependents) is not enough, the development package *LibOpenCV-Dev* (*libopencv-dev*) is required.

> ```
> [064bit prompt]> apt list | grep libopencv-dev
>
> WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
>
> libopencv-dev/jammy,now 4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
> ```

Example making use of it.

*main00.cpp*:

```c
#include <opencv2/core/types.hpp>

#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    cv::Mat mat(100, 100, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
    printf("\nDone.\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> main00.cpp
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> # ---------- WRONG ORDER ----------
> [064bit prompt]> g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4) main00.cpp -o main00
> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc79oIaV.o: in function `main':
> main00.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&)'
> /usr/bin/ld: main00.cpp:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
> /usr/bin/ld: main00.cpp:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> # ---------- RIGHT ORDER ----------
> [064bit prompt]> g++ main00.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4) -o main00
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> main00  main00.cpp
> [064bit prompt]> ldd main00
>     linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdeb2c6000)
>     libopencv_core.so.4.5d => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.4.5d (0x00007f7551e00000)
>     libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7551a00000)
>     libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7552188000)
>     libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7551600000)
>     libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f7551de4000)
>     libtbb.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2 (0x00007f7551d9e000)
>     libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7551cb7000)
>     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f75521d2000)
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ./main00
>
> Done.
> ```

The ordering difference (fail / success) is due to the fact that the ***GNU Linker* resolves symbols** (in passed objects and libraries) **from left to right**.
Leaving the source file (and its corresponding object (*.o*) file) at the end, leaves it with unresolved symbols (in spite of the libraries containing those symbols being passed before it - and thus already searched). For more details, check [[SO]: Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135/4788546).
So this part **has nothing to do with *Pkg-Config*, *OpenCV***, or any other package as a matter of fact, it's a generic *GNU Linker* feature.