# Why does my g++ compiler not find the right OpenCV version?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, g++

I am trying to compile a program using this command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.0_5/include/opencv4/opencv2/" -I"/usr/include/python2.7" stl.cpp -o stl -ldl -lpthread -lrt -lopencv_core -lpython2.7
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
fatal error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
```

I changed my -I include path to point to my version of OpenCV that has opencv2/core.hpp properly installed. Am I missing something? This approach has worked for other compilations...

#### EDIT

After trying the suggestions below, I'm still having no luck.

I added the pkg-config suggestion like below:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I"/usr/include/python2.7" stl.cpp -o stl -ldl -lpthread -lrt -lopencv_core -lpython2.7  `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

but I still get `"opencv2/core.hpp"` not found. This is weird because when I run:

`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`

I get:

`-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.0_5/include/opencv4 -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.0_5/lib -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_alphamat -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_intensity_transform -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_mcc -lopencv_quality -lopencv_rapid -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_viz -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core`
which makes me think it should work.

I also tried changing `#include opencv2/core.hpp` to `#include core.hpp`. This gets me closer, but then I get an error in my actual opencv2/core.hpp file saying it can't find the includes anymore. I don't think I want to start editing include paths in the original opencv library.

Comment: You want to look into the pkg-config tool. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/q/15113753/451600

Comment: try to compile by the command /* g++ -std=c++11 stl.cpp -o output ` pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` */ if u re using hte version of opencv below than 4 than replace opencv4 with only opencv

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your include path is a bit wrong.
With your `-I` path you are looking at `...opencv4/opencv2/`. And when you include `core.hpp` you are including it with (presumably):

```cpp
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
```

So the compiler is basically looking for `core.hpp` at: `...opencv4/opencv2/opencv2/core.hpp`.

Try using `...include/opencv4/` instead. Or include like so:

```cpp
#include "core.hpp"
```

Comment: better to use ` \`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4\` `  as gcc flag

Comment: I tried both options but could not find a solution, see edits. Thank you.

Comment: try without `-lopencv_core `.